# Error Using Python's "Scrapy"

Tags: python, scrapy

I installed the newest version of Scrapy on Python 2.7 (Yes, I still use this version) and am getting an error while running Scrapy's tutorial script.
The code I'm running is:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmoz.org"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)
```

**The error is:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Rainey/Desktop/dmoz/spiders/dmoz_spider.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spider.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapy import log
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\log.py", line 10, in <module>
    from twisted.python import log
ImportError: No module named twisted.python
```

The tutorial script is on my desktop. Will this effect and should I have it in a different place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message '*ImportError: No module named twisted.python*' indicates that you are missing the [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) module.

Install twisted using a package manager like pip or [download a Windows binary](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads).

Answer (score 2):

You did not install scrapy successfully on windows. following steps should work for you to install scrapy 0.14(latest) on windows.

1. Install lxml-2.3 using windows installer [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/2.3). I tried libxml but not work.
2. Install Twisted-12.0.0 using windows installer [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Twisted/12.0.0)
3. Install zope.interface with Mingw32 or not.
4. Install pyOpenSSL 0.13 using windows installer [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL/0.13)
5. run "**pip install scrapy**", you are ready to go!

Hope it helps.